# How Does RL continuous control via Gaussian policy work?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gaussian

I'm implementing Soft-Actor-Critic algorithm but I'm not able to understand how the stocastic policy works. I've searched online but I don't find any site interesting that explains well the following implementation. The only thing that I understood is that in the case of stocastic policy we model it as a Gaussian and we parametrize the mean and the log std (I think that std is standard deviation) but for example: why do we need the log std and not just std?

```
class ActorNetwork(object):
    def __init__(self, act_dim, name):
        self.act_dim = act_dim
        self.name = name

    def step(self, obs, log_std_min=-20, log_std_max=2): 
        with tf.variable_scope(self.name, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):

            h1 = tf.layers.dense(obs, 256, tf.nn.relu)
            h2 = tf.layers.dense(h1, 256, tf.nn.relu) 
            mu = tf.layers.dense(h2, self.act_dim, None)
            log_std = tf.layers.dense(h2, self.act_dim, tf.tanh)
            '''
            at the start we could have extremely large values for the log_stds, which could result in some actions 
            being either entirely deterministic or too random. To protect against that, 
            we'll constrain the output range of the log_stds, to be within [LOG_STD_MIN, LOG_STD_MAX]
            ''' 
            log_std = log_std_min + 0.5 * (log_std_max - log_std_min) * (log_std + 1)

            std = tf.exp(log_std)
            pi = mu + tf.random_normal(tf.shape(mu)) * std 

            #gaussian likelihood
            pre_sum = -0.5 * (((pi - mu) / (tf.exp(log_std) + EPS)) ** 2 + 2 * log_std + np.log(2 * np.pi)) 
            logp_pi = tf.reduce_sum(pre_sum, axis=1) 

            mu = tf.tanh(mu)
            pi = tf.tanh(pi)

            clip_pi = 1 - tf.square(pi) #pi^2
            clip_up = tf.cast(clip_pi > 1, tf.float32)
            clip_low = tf.cast(clip_pi < 0, tf.float32)
            clip_pi = clip_pi + tf.stop_gradient((1 - clip_pi) * clip_up + (0 - clip_pi) * clip_low)

            logp_pi -= tf.reduce_sum(tf.log(clip_pi + 1e-6), axis=1) 

        return mu, pi, logp_pi

    def evaluate(self, obs): #Choose action
        mu, pi, logp_pi = self.step(obs)
        action_scale = 2.0 # env.action_space.high[0]

        mu *= action_scale
        pi *= action_scale
        return mu, pi, logp_pi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. In Gaussian policies, you map from an observation (using a policy network) to a mean value, `mu`, and the logarithm of standard deviation, `log_std` of actions. It is because you have a continues action space. Once you trained your model to assign `mu` and `log_std` in the action space, you calculate log-likelihood of taking action sampled by `pi.`

In Gaussian policies, `log_std` is preferred over `std`, only because `log_std` takes any values in (-inf,+inf) while `std` is limited to non-negative values. Being free from this non-negativity constraint makes training easier, and also you don't lose any information by this conversion.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation is very clear. What about clip_pi? I've seen that "tf.cast(clip_pi > 1, tf.float32)" turns into 1 everything that is more than 1, while "tf.cast(clip_pi < 0, tf.float32)" turns into 1 everything that is less than 0 but why do I need this?

Comment: In SAC, clipping part is normally for implementing the target policy smoothing, which is adding a clipped noise on each dimension of the action, as regularization. But here, I did not understand the purpose. For more clear SAC implementation, you can check [OpenAI spinning up course](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/algorithms/sac.html). Please upvote if it answers your question.